# create a dataframe with multilevel columns( 3rd level columns under one of the second level column)

Tags: python, dataframe, multi-level

I want to create a dataframe similar to following excel sheet :

[image]

I tried following code

```py
# Convert 'Transaction Date' column to string format
data_df['Transaction Date'] = data_df['Transaction Date'].astype(str)

# Extract aisle from bin column
data_df['Aisle'] = data_df['Bin'].str[0]

# Group the data by aisle, employee, and date, and calculate count and quantity picked
by_Aisle = data_df.groupby(['Aisle', 'User', 'Transaction Date']).agg({'Product': 'size', 'Qty': lambda x: x.abs().sum()}).reset_index()
by_Aisle = by_Aisle.rename(columns={'Transaction Date': 'Date', 'Product': 'Count'})

# Pivot the table to reshape the data
by_Aisle = by_Aisle.pivot_table(index='User', columns=['Date', 'Aisle'], values=['Count', 'Qty'], fill_value='')

# Flatten the column names and set multi-level columns
by_Aisle.columns = by_Aisle.columns.map('_'.join)

# Sort the columns in chronological order
by_Aisle = by_Aisle.sort_index(axis=1, level=0)

# Reset the index name for the 'User' column
by_Aisle.index.name = 'User'
```

but not working. please help

Comment: This question needs some edit suggestions

Comment: Do you need to create a template (*like in the image*) and/or populate it with a *DataFrame* ?

Comment: If it's 2, can you `print(data_df.sample(10).to_dict())` ? Otherwise, you can try my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to make the template in the image, I would use [xlsxwriter](/questions/tagged/xlsxwriter) (*for more flexibility*) :

```
# to be adjusted (if needed)
l1 = pd.date_range("20221012", "20221013")
l2 = ["Aisle", "Count", "Qty"]
l3 = list(range(1,5)) + list("ABC") + [""]*2
idx = ["User"] + list("ABCDFEGHIJ")

df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(index=idx, columns=l3)]*len(l1), axis=1)

with pd.ExcelWriter("output.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter") as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, startrow=2, sheet_name="MySheet", index_label="Aisle")
    wb, ws = writer.book, writer.sheets["MySheet"]
    
    cf = wb.add_format({
        "align": "center", "valign": "vcenter",
        "border": 1, "bold": 1, "font_size": 11}
    )
    
    ws.write(0, 0, "Date", cf)

    for i, d in enumerate(l1, start=1):
        ws.merge_range(
            0, (i-1)*len(l3) + 1, 0, i*len(l3), d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), cf)

    for i in range(1, len(df.columns)-2, len(l3)):
        ws.merge_range(1, i, 1, i+(len(l3)-3), l2[0], cf)
        ws.write(1, i+(len(l3)-3)+1, l2[1], cf)
        ws.write(1, i+(len(l3)-3)+2, l2[2], cf)
    
    ws.conditional_format(
        3, 1, len(df)+2, len(df.columns),
        {"type": "blanks", "format": wb.add_format({"border": 1})}
    )
```

Output (`output.xlsx`) :

[image]